# Java client HTTP request with cookie that sets a domain, expiry, etc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I can easily write Java client code that specify a cookie, where the cookie has a **name** and **value**. However, I cannot get this working for a cookie that also needs to specify a **domain**, and/or an **expiry**, and/or a **path**.

When i specify my cookie as:

```
cookieName=cookieValue; Expires=Wed, 21 Jun 2023 10:00:00 GMT; Domain=example.com
```

2 cookies are created, (as in, this is what the server sees),

```
cookieName=cookieValue
Domain=example.com
```

I am able to easily replicate this using Spring Boot setup;

```
package com.example;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplate;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.RequestEntity;

import java.net.URI;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class TestTest {

  @Value(value = "${local.server.port}")
  private int port;

  @Autowired
  private TestRestTemplate client;

  @Test
  public void cookie() {

    // Setup
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, "cookieName=cookieValue; Expires=Wed, 21 Jun 2023 10:00:00 GMT; Domain=example.com");

    // Create the RequestEntity with the desired HTTP method, URL, and headers
    RequestEntity<Void> requestEntity = new RequestEntity<>(headers, HttpMethod.GET, URI.create("http://localhost:" + port + "/test"));

    // Send the request and print the response
    System.out.println(client.exchange(requestEntity, String.class));
  }
}
```

```
package com.example;


import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

@RestController
public class TestController {
  @GetMapping("/test")
  public ResponseEntity<List<String>> test(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Stream<String> stringStream = Arrays.stream(request.getCookies()).map(it -> String.format("Name: %s, Value: %s, Domain: %s, Path: %s, Age: %s", it.getName(), it.getValue(), it.getDomain(), it.getPath(), it.getMaxAge()));
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(stringStream.collect(Collectors.toList()));
  }
}
```

Output:

```
<200 OK 
  OK,["Name: cookieName, Value: cookieValue, Domain: null, Path: null, Age: -1",
      "Name: Domain, Value: example.com, Domain: null, Path: null, Age: -1"],
  [Content-Type:"application/json", 
   Transfer-Encoding:"chunked", 
   Date:"Thu, 15 Jun 2023 21:19:18 GMT", 
   Keep-Alive:"timeout=60", 
   Connection:"keep-alive"]>
```

I am baffled, and have tried a a few diff clients and using http servlet types and spring types, but same end result. Not sure if cookie is somehow truncating or what.

As an example of something else i tried, and had same outcome (i.e. 2 cookies "created" by http request object on the server):

```
    org.springframework.http.ResponseCookie cookie = ResponseCookie.from("meadow", "SOPRANO")
        .path("/prod")  // Set the desired path for the cookie
        .maxAge(3600)  // Set the expiry time in seconds (e.g., 1 hour)
        .domain("foo.com")
        .build();

    // Setup
    final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.COOKIE, cookie.toString());
```

Thanks

Comment: Ty chatgpt: "When sending cookies in an HTTP request, it's important to understand that certain properties like cookie expiry, domain, and path are typically handled by the client (browser) and are not sent explicitly to the server as part of the request."